# Is it possible to read from console in Dart?

Tags: console, dart

I know that we can print to the console in dart using the print() statement.

I want to know if it is possible to read data from console. I did a search and also looked in the dart:io package, but couldn't find any reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [StringInputStream](http://api.dartlang.org/io/StringInputStream.html) to read from stdin like this

```dart
#import("dart:io");

main() { 
  var stream = new StringInputStream(stdin); 
  stream.onLine = () { 
    var line = stream.readLine(); 
    if (line != null) { 
      print(line); 
    } 
  }; 
}
```

also if you're developing a console application then checkout the [Options](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_core/Options.html) class to parse command line arguments

```dart
final args = new Options().arguments;
```

Comment: StringInputStream API has been deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440138/how-to-read-console-input-on-m3-dart