# How do I simulate blocking on StringInputStream readLine in Dart?

Tags: console, dart

I found the answer for being able to read from the console here: [Is it possible to read from console in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257744/is-it-possible-to-read-from-console-in-dart).  However, I want to block further execution in my program until the string is typed in (think just simple console interaction with the user).

However, I'm not seeing a way to control the execution flow for simple interaction.  I realize that Dart I/O is intended to be asynchronous, so I'm struggling to figure out how I should accomplish this seemingly simple task.  Is it just that I'm trying to use Dart for something that it was not intended to do?

```
#import("dart:io");

void main() {
  var yourName;
  var yourAge; 
  var console = new StringInputStream(stdin);

  print("Please enter your name? ");
  console.onLine = () {
    yourName = console.readLine();
    print("Hello $yourName");
  };

  // obviously the rest of this doesn't work...
  print("Please enter your age? ");
  console.onLine = () { 
    yourAge = console.readLine();
    print("You are $yourAge years old");
  };

  print("Hello $yourName, you are $yourAge years old today!");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answering my own question)

Dart has added several features since this question was originally asked, specifically, the concept of readLineSync using stdin.  This tutorial covers several of the typical topics you might need to be aware of if writing a command-line Dart app: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/cmdline/

```
import "dart:io";

void main() {
    stdout.writeln('Please enter your name? ');
    String yourName = stdin.readLineSync();
    stdout.writeln('Hello $yourName');

    stdout.writeln('Please enter your age? ');
    String yourAge = stdin.readLineSync();
    stdout.writeln('You are $yourAge years old');

    stdout.writeln('Hello $yourName, you are $yourAge years old today!');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope that in the future, all IO will be done via `Future`s. In the meantime, you have two options:

1. Use callbacks, as you write in your question. `Future`s aren't the only way to deal with asynchronous execution. I'm in fact kinda surprised that you ask, because your question already contains this answer -- just move your code a little bit:

   ```
   void main() {
     var stream = new StringInputStream(stdin); 
     stream.onLine = () { 
       var myString = stream.readLine();
       print("This was after the handler $myString");

       // I want to wait until myString is typed in

       print("echo $myString"); // should not print null
     }; 
   }
   ```
2. Write your own wrapper that returns `Future`. It would probably look something like this (warning: didn't test it!):

   ```
   class MyStringInputStream {
     final StringInputStream delegate;

     MyStringInputStream(InputStream stream)
         : delegate = new StringInputStream(stream);

     Future<String> readLine() {
       final completer = new Completer<String>();

       delegate.onLine = () {
         final line = delegate.readLine();
         delegate.onLine = null;
         completer.complete(line);
       };

       return completer.future;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks - I think that I understand better, but what I'm trying to do is very simple but maybe not what Dart is being designed to do.  Basically, I'm attempting to re-write an old script in Dart as a learning tool, but I've found it very difficult to do something like wait for the user input from the console before continuing (think gets.chomp in Ruby or a BufferedReader readLine in Java).  I may have to completely rethink the code structure as part of this exercise.