# Dart native extension: How to create "Push" data stream

Tags: dart, dart-native-extension

I'll refer conceptually to "*Pushed*" vs "*Polled*" streams to help describe my question's objective which is to "*Create a *Pushed* data stream emulating the data flow behavior of Dart's stdin stream*"

"*Polled*": In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945732/dart-how-to-create-stream-in-native-extension/24962112?noredirect=1#comment38809315_24962112), Menzoni's answer is a great example of a "*Polled*" stream. The stream is always initiated and data-requested *from* the Dart console app *to* the native-extension.  The request is fulfilled and a response returns to the app. This is typical of Dart stream usage from my experience.

"*Pushed*": Data arriving from an external source pushed down to the console app. Data origin and transport technology doesn't matter, it could be stdin keyboard/mouse events,PLC interrupts, database async notifications, etc.

I'll use the stdin stream for purpose of this illustration, its a good example of the data flow I'm trying to achieve. Data in the form of virtualkeycodes/ints arrive within the native extension, buffered, then need to be "*Pushed*" (sent/posted) to the Dart app without requiring any pull/poll requests for data from the app. This is the objective I'm trying to achieve in my native-extension's custom stream!

Dart console app pseudo-code:

```dart
Stream<List<int>> virtKeyCodes = NativeCreatePushedStream_Keycodes();   
virtKeyCodes.listen(processInts);
void processInts(List<int> kbinput) {
    print("processInts: found ${kbinput.length} kbinput chars");
    for (int i = 0; i < kbinput.length; i++) {
        print("...kbinput:${kbinput[i]}");
    }
}
```

Native extension pseudo-code(**I'm guessing here!**)

```dart
Initial call create persistant stream
Return to console app where it starts to listen
onDataReady somehow post ints to stream
DartVM pushes to console app
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing a "Pushed" data-stream via [asynchronous native extension](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/#the-asynchronous-native-extension)

Created [dxConsole](https://github.com/osstekz/dxConsole) "Dart Console Library for Windows" project, now hosted on Github.